# Porting API function to Lua

Tags: lua

Can someone give me any suggestions as to how to use this function from Lua:

[HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms670084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN)

I'm just a bit confused as to how to call the function as in is it from a dll or do I need to make a dll or is this a Luacom type of scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua cannot go out into random DLLs and start calling random C functions<sup>1</sup>. If you want to call some code in a DLL, then you need to write a proper Lua module in C that will load this DLL and marshall the call from Lua to the DLL. Lua can read regular Lua modules and act accordingly.

<sup>1</sup>: If you're using LuaJIT, you can do this via their FFI stuff. To a degree, as you'll need to provide a string describing the interface for the functions you want to call.